# How to Optimize Data Grid View Loading Time

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm retrieving a datatable from the user and displaying it in a data grid view. However, when the dataset is extensive, it takes a significant amount of time to load. To address this, I've implemented restrictions on the number of rows and columns that can be displayed, aligning with the maximum limits of Excel (17,000 columns and 1,050,000 rows).

The primary objective of my WinForms application is to swiftly present data from the datatable. If the loading process takes this much time, it's unlikely that users would find the visualization of the datatable at such a slow speed appealing.

Once the data is loaded, navigation is smooth with no issues. However, the problem arises when I attempt to sort columns or rearrange their positions by dragging. At that point, the application initiates a loading process and freezes for a few seconds.

**DT_Visualize.cs**

```
namespace Datatable_Visualizer_Activity
{
    public partial class DatatableVisualizerForm : Form
    {
        private DataTable dataTable;
        public DatatableVisualizerForm(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            InitializeComponent();
            this.dataTable = dataTable;
            bunifuDataGridView.Visible = false;
            ShowLoading(true);


            // Continue with the rest of your code
            InitializeDataGridViewAsync();
        }
        private void ShowLoading(bool show)
        {
            progressBar.Visible = show;
        }

        private async void InitializeDataGridViewAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Simulate a delay for loading data (replace this with your actual data loading logic)
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

                // Invoke on UI thread to update UI controls
                Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                   
                   
                    // Bind the DataTable to the DataGridView
                    bunifuDataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
                    // Auto resize columns
                    bunifuDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
                    bunifuDataGridView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing;
                    bunifuDataGridView.DoubleBuffered(true);



                    // Set labels based on the initial state
                    label_TotalNoColumns.Text = "Total No Of Columns = " + dataTable.Columns.Count.ToString();
                    label_TotalNoRows.Text = "Total No Of Rows = " + dataTable.Rows.Count.ToString();
                    ShowLoading(false); // Hide the circular progress bar
                    bunifuDataGridView.Visible = true; // Show the DataGridView
                }));
            });
        }

        private void dataGridView_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Column.FillWeight = 10;
        }

        private void bunifuDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
        {
            Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
            PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**DT_VisualizerDesigner.cs**

```
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle4 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle5 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle6 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            this.materialDivider1 = new MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialDivider();
            this.label_TotalRows = new MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialLabel();
            this.label_TotalNoColumns = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label_TotalNoRows = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.progressBar = new CircularProgressBar.CircularProgressBar();
            this.dataGridView = new Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuDataGridView();
            this.bunifuDataGridView = new Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuDataGridView();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bunifuDataGridView)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // materialDivider1
            // 
            this.materialDivider1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.materialDivider1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(18)))), ((int)(((byte)(18)))), ((int)(((byte)(18)))));
            this.materialDivider1.Depth = 0;
            this.materialDivider1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.materialDivider1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 497);
            this.materialDivider1.MouseState = MaterialSkin.MouseState.HOVER;
            this.materialDivider1.Name = "materialDivider1";
            this.materialDivider1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(921, 9);
            this.materialDivider1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.materialDivider1.Text = "materialDivider1";
            // 
            // label_TotalRows
            // 
            this.label_TotalRows.Depth = 0;
            this.label_TotalRows.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11F);
            this.label_TotalRows.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(222)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
            this.label_TotalRows.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.label_TotalRows.MouseState = MaterialSkin.MouseState.HOVER;
            this.label_TotalRows.Name = "label_TotalRows";
            this.label_TotalRows.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 23);
            this.label_TotalRows.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // label_TotalNoColumns
            // 
            this.label_TotalNoColumns.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
            this.label_TotalNoColumns.AutoSize = true;
            this.label_TotalNoColumns.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 11F);
            this.label_TotalNoColumns.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.label_TotalNoColumns.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 560);
            this.label_TotalNoColumns.Name = "label_TotalNoColumns";
            this.label_TotalNoColumns.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(161, 20);
            this.label_TotalNoColumns.TabIndex = 8;
            this.label_TotalNoColumns.Text = "Total No Of Columns =";
            // 
            // label_TotalNoRows
            // 
            this.label_TotalNoRows.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
            this.label_TotalNoRows.AutoSize = true;
            this.label_TotalNoRows.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 11F);
            this.label_TotalNoRows.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.label_TotalNoRows.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 532);
            this.label_TotalNoRows.Name = "label_TotalNoRows";
            this.label_TotalNoRows.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(139, 20);
            this.label_TotalNoRows.TabIndex = 8;
            this.label_TotalNoRows.Text = "Total No Of Rows =";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(426, 560);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(118, 28);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 9;
            this.button1.Text = "Editable = False";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(804, 532);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(118, 28);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 9;
            this.button2.Text = "Done";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this.button3.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.button3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(804, 565);
            this.button3.Name = "button3";
            this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(118, 28);
            this.button3.TabIndex = 9;
            this.button3.Text = "Cancel";
            this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            // 
            // progressBar
            // 
            this.progressBar.AnimationFunction = WinFormAnimation.KnownAnimationFunctions.Liner;
            this.progressBar.AnimationSpeed = 500;
            this.progressBar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.progressBar.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 72F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.progressBar.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.progressBar.InnerColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.progressBar.InnerMargin = 2;
            this.progressBar.InnerWidth = -1;
            this.progressBar.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(426, 204);
            this.progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 2000;
            this.progressBar.Name = "progressBar";
            this.progressBar.OuterColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
            this.progressBar.OuterMargin = -25;
            this.progressBar.OuterWidth = 26;
            this.progressBar.ProgressColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.progressBar.ProgressWidth = 5;
            this.progressBar.SecondaryFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 36F);
            this.progressBar.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(111, 112);
            this.progressBar.StartAngle = 270;
            this.progressBar.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            this.progressBar.SubscriptColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(166)))), ((int)(((byte)(166)))), ((int)(((byte)(166)))));
            this.progressBar.SubscriptMargin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, -35, 0, 0);
            this.progressBar.SubscriptText = ".23";
            this.progressBar.SuperscriptColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(166)))), ((int)(((byte)(166)))), ((int)(((byte)(166)))));
            this.progressBar.SuperscriptMargin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 35, 0, 0);
            this.progressBar.SuperscriptText = "°C";
            this.progressBar.TabIndex = 10;
            this.progressBar.TextMargin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(8, 8, 0, 0);
            this.progressBar.Value = 68;
            // 
            // dataGridView
            // 
            this.dataGridView.AllowCustomTheming = false;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(248)))), ((int)(((byte)(251)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.dataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
            this.dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            this.dataGridView.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            this.dataGridView.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
            this.dataGridView.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue;
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 11.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(24)))), ((int)(((byte)(115)))), ((int)(((byte)(204)))));
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            dataGridViewCellStyle2.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
            this.dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
            this.dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40;
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.AlternatingRowsStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(248)))), ((int)(((byte)(251)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.AlternatingRowsStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.AlternatingRowsStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.AlternatingRowsStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(210)))), ((int)(((byte)(232)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.AlternatingRowsStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.GridColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(221)))), ((int)(((byte)(238)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue;
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.HeaderStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 11.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.HeaderStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(24)))), ((int)(((byte)(115)))), ((int)(((byte)(204)))));
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.HeaderStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.Name = null;
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.RowsStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.RowsStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.RowsStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.RowsStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(210)))), ((int)(((byte)(232)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.dataGridView.CurrentTheme.RowsStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(210)))), ((int)(((byte)(232)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            dataGridViewCellStyle3.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False;
            this.dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle3;
            this.dataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            this.dataGridView.GridColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(221)))), ((int)(((byte)(238)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.dataGridView.HeaderBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue;
            this.dataGridView.HeaderBgColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            this.dataGridView.HeaderForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.dataGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.dataGridView.Name = "dataGridView";
            this.dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            this.dataGridView.RowTemplate.Height = 40;
            this.dataGridView.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            this.dataGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 150);
            this.dataGridView.TabIndex = 0;
            this.dataGridView.Theme = Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuDataGridView.PresetThemes.Light;
            // 
            // bunifuDataGridView
            // 
            this.bunifuDataGridView.AllowCustomTheming = false;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
            dataGridViewCellStyle4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(44)))), ((int)(((byte)(48)))), ((int)(((byte)(52)))));
            dataGridViewCellStyle4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle4;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(18)))), ((int)(((byte)(18)))), ((int)(((byte)(18)))));
            this.bunifuDataGridView.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.ClipboardCopyMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(15)))), ((int)(((byte)(16)))), ((int)(((byte)(18)))));
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 11.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(63)))), ((int)(((byte)(63)))), ((int)(((byte)(65)))));
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            dataGridViewCellStyle5.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle5;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.AlternatingRowsStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(44)))), ((int)(((byte)(48)))), ((int)(((byte)(52)))));
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.AlternatingRowsStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.AlternatingRowsStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.AlternatingRowsStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(114)))), ((int)(((byte)(117)))), ((int)(((byte)(119)))));
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.AlternatingRowsStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(15)))), ((int)(((byte)(16)))), ((int)(((byte)(18)))));
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.GridColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(50)))), ((int)(((byte)(56)))), ((int)(((byte)(62)))));
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(15)))), ((int)(((byte)(16)))), ((int)(((byte)(18)))));
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.HeaderStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 11.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.HeaderStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(63)))), ((int)(((byte)(63)))), ((int)(((byte)(65)))));
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.HeaderStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.Name = null;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.RowsStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(33)))), ((int)(((byte)(37)))), ((int)(((byte)(41)))));
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.RowsStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.RowsStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.RowsStyle.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(114)))), ((int)(((byte)(117)))), ((int)(((byte)(119)))));
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CurrentTheme.RowsStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            dataGridViewCellStyle6.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            dataGridViewCellStyle6.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(33)))), ((int)(((byte)(37)))), ((int)(((byte)(41)))));
            dataGridViewCellStyle6.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            dataGridViewCellStyle6.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            dataGridViewCellStyle6.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(114)))), ((int)(((byte)(117)))), ((int)(((byte)(119)))));
            dataGridViewCellStyle6.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            dataGridViewCellStyle6.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle6;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.GridColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(50)))), ((int)(((byte)(56)))), ((int)(((byte)(62)))));
            this.bunifuDataGridView.HeaderBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(15)))), ((int)(((byte)(16)))), ((int)(((byte)(18)))));
            this.bunifuDataGridView.HeaderBgColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.HeaderForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 12);
            this.bunifuDataGridView.Name = "bunifuDataGridView";
            this.bunifuDataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.RowTemplate.Height = 40;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(920, 479);
            this.bunifuDataGridView.TabIndex = 11;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.Theme = Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuDataGridView.PresetThemes.Dark;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.VirtualMode = true;
            this.bunifuDataGridView.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.bunifuDataGridView_CellContentClick);
            // 
            // DatatableVisualizerForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(942, 608);
            this.Controls.Add(this.bunifuDataGridView);
            this.Controls.Add(this.progressBar);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label_TotalNoRows);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label_TotalNoColumns);
            this.Controls.Add(this.materialDivider1);
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "DatatableVisualizerForm";
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "DataTable Visualizer & Editor";
            this.TopMost = true;
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bunifuDataGridView)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }
```

Comment: @b166er but will this solve my issue ?

Comment: @sagar-raval In terms of responsiveness it will definitely make a huge improvement, it's a good start but there are many other things that can be done to optimize large datasets, starting with chunking data.

Comment: @b166er could you share some code of what you are trying to say ' You will need to implement this with an Init method that will runs as a async Task'

i have converted the method into  private async Task InitializeDataGridViewAsync(), is this what you meant ?

Comment: @JonasH thanks , but the link is broken

Comment: Oups, try this one: [Data Grid virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: @b166er & JonasH ,im sorry but i made a mistake about describing the question , the issue is not with the form loading time the issue is with the datagridview time , as the datagridview gets lots of data the form get stuck

Comment: right now  , my form is running from last 20 min and isnt even able to load the 1,050,000 rows with 8 columns only , im not even tested the 17000 coulmns limit

Comment: @sagar-raval That is a huge amount of data to display in a grid, do you need to pull as much data or can you aggregate or group the data into more condensed bits? How and where are you getting the data? What is your end goal, because the other problem is that this amount of data in excel will probably be unusable as an Excel document as well.

Comment: @b166er, my ultimate objective is to present a table view for UiPath developers, allowing them to quickly inspect and edit the data within their DataTable. The aim is to provide a seamless experience. While considering the option of limiting the rows to a very small number, it raises the question of the developers' ability to simply check the Excel files if the data set is too restricted.

Comment: @b166er 
Adding a note to highlight, I am taking a visible No Of Rows as input from the developers. Despite the predefined limit being 1,050,000 rows, developers can now specify the exact number of rows they wish to visualize. This approach effectively reducing the computational load. (but this is an optional feature)

Comment: @sagar-raval First off, I assume you have removed the Thread.Sleep(3000), socondly, try to remove these lines: bunifuDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
                    bunifuDataGridView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing;

Comment: @b166er, I have removed the `bunifuDataGridView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing;`, but I encountered an issue after removing the `Thread.Sleep(3000)`. I am getting an error in the async method. Although the initial problem of slow DataGridView data loading has been resolved by using `ResizeColumn` to `DisplayedCells`, significantly improving the speed by almost 60%. Now, as I am considering finalizing this code for production, could you please review it and provide suggestions? [CodeShare Link](https://codeshare.io/1VoYn1)